# Application suddenly hangs (Waiting to enter a .NET Lock)

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have an application running on IIS 8.5 and it suddenly hangs.

I've dumped the memory on the exactly moment and tried to analyse the problem and I found the following:

> The following threads in w3wp.exe_210419_122423.dmp are waiting to enter a .NET Lock which is owned by thread 128

If I understood the message, this means that one thread is locking the others (76 threads) but I didn't figured out what exactly is happening.

Looking at thread 128, I've got the following:

```
Thread 128 - System ID 27172
Entry point   clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc
Create time   19/04/2021 12:06:21
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.734
Time spent in kernel mode     0 Days 00:00:00.171

This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.

.NET Call Stack

[[HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ] (System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal)] System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
System.Threading.Thread.Abort(System.Object)+56
System.Web.RequestTimeoutManager+RequestTimeoutEntry.TimeoutIfNeeded(System.DateTime)+42
System.Web.RequestTimeoutManager.CancelTimedOutRequests(System.DateTime)+1a3
System.Web.RequestTimeoutManager.TimerCompletionCallback(System.Object)+1e
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+16a
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+14
System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()+13b
System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()+8f
System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()+75
[[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]]
[[ContextTransitionFrame]]
[[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]]

Full Call Stack


Instruction Address       Source
[0x7ffe39ee0c6a]    ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+a      
[0x7ffe370713ed]    KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+e1    
[0x7ffe1dc896be]    clr!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx_SO_TOLERANT+62   
[0x7ffe1dc8951c]    clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+1e4   
[0x7ffe1dc89315]    clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+7d      
[0x7ffe1db5f256]    clr!Thread::JoinEx+a2     
[0x7ffe1defe453]    clr!Thread::UserAbort+6d8     
[0x7ffe1e0090f7]    clr!ThreadNative::Abort+117   
[0x7ffdc0913ed6]    System.Threading.Thread.Abort(System.Object)+56   
[0x7ffdc090bd52]    System.Web.RequestTimeoutManager+RequestTimeoutEntry.TimeoutIfNeeded(System.DateTime)+42      
[0x7ffdc090af93]    System.Web.RequestTimeoutManager.CancelTimedOutRequests(System.DateTime)+1a3      
[0x7ffdc0909b7e]    System.Web.RequestTimeoutManager.TimerCompletionCallback(System.Object)+1e    
[0x7ffdbea0c77a]    System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+16a    
[0x7ffdbea09fe4]    System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+14     
[0x7ffdbef7ac1b]    System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()+13b   
[0x7ffdbef7a7af]    System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()+8f    
[0x7ffdbef79245]    System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()+75   
[0x7ffe1dae6bb3]    clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+83    
[0x7ffe1dae6a70]    clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+4e     
[0x7ffe1dae735d]    clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+f8   
[0x7ffe1dae9ff3]    clr!AppDomainTimerCallback_Worker+23      
[0x7ffe1dae7b21]    clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+39    
[0x7ffe1dae7a90]    clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+6c   
[0x7ffe1dae79cd]    clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+75    
[0x7ffe1daeaa64]    clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInCorrectAD+15      
[0x7ffe1daeab5e]    clr!Thread::DoADCallBack+278      
[0x7ffe1daeaab3]    clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+2fd3      
[0x7ffe1dae7a90]    clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+6c   
[0x7ffe1dae79cd]    clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+75    
[0x7ffe1dae7b5f]    clr!ManagedThreadBase_FullTransitionWithAD+2f     
[0x7ffe1dae9f85]    clr!AppDomainTimerCallback+7f     
[0x7ffe1dae9ee6]    clr!ThreadpoolMgr::AsyncTimerCallbackCompletion+7e    
[0x7ffe1dae99e7]    clr!UnManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+1bc    
[0x7ffe1dae819c]    clr!ThreadpoolMgr::ExecuteWorkRequest+64      
[0x7ffe1dae7f45]    clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+f5   
[0x7ffe1db92e8f]    clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+86     
[0x7ffe375a13d2]    kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+22   
[0x7ffe39e654e4]    ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+34
```

Does anyone know what is happening and how can I solve it?

Thank you!!

Comment: Might it be that you have started some neverending process and are trying to wait for it?

Comment: A hang dump only captured a snapshot of that process, so not all necessary information is inside to rebuild the whole crime scene. But this call stack does indicate ASP.NET runtime was trying to abort long running requests, https://www.programmersought.com/article/15483747735/ so you should check why there were so many requests to be aborted. Profiling and more application level logging should reveal more hints.

Answer (score 1):

Make it all call as asyc and you will get resolve the issue, also change max number of concurrently executing requests per CPU as high